# Haproxy GZIP is not a supported algorithm

Tags: haproxy

I am trying to use GZIP with Haproxy and I have it compiled with ZLIB but I still get a parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:33] : 'compression' : 'gzip' is not a supported algorithm error.

Haproxy -vv

```
    HA-Proxy version 1.6.9 2016/08/30
Copyright 2000-2016 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>

Build options :
  TARGET  = linux2628
  CPU     = generic
  CC      = gcc
  CFLAGS  = -O2 -g -fno-strict-aliasing -DTCP_USER_TIMEOUT=18
  OPTIONS = USE_LINUX_TPROXY=1 USE_ZLIB=1 USE_REGPARM=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_PCRE=1 USE_PCRE_JIT=1

Default settings :
  maxconn = 2000, bufsize = 16384, maxrewrite = 1024, maxpollevents = 200

Encrypted password support via crypt(3): yes
Built with zlib version : 1.2.7
Compression algorithms supported : identity("identity"), deflate("deflate"), raw-deflate("deflate"), gzip("gzip")
Built with OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
Running on OpenSSL version : OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
OpenSSL library supports TLS extensions : yes
OpenSSL library supports SNI : yes
OpenSSL library supports prefer-server-ciphers : yes
Built with PCRE version : 8.32 2012-11-30
PCRE library supports JIT : yes
Built without Lua support
Built with transparent proxy support using: IP_TRANSPARENT IPV6_TRANSPARENT IP_FREEBIND

Available polling systems :
      epoll : pref=300,  test result OK
       poll : pref=200,  test result OK
     select : pref=150,  test result OK
Total: 3 (3 usable), will use epoll.
```

Comment: What's the complete line 33 from the config file?

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. When I try `make USE_ZLIB=yes`, it works!

```sh
make -j $(nproc) TARGET=generic USE_GZIP=1 USE_OPENSSL=1 USE_ZLIB=yes SSL_INC=/usr/local/include SSL_LIB=/usr/local/lib64
```

see https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-and-gzip-compression/